# The sys, subprocess, timeit packages are missing from the PyPi site

Tags: python, docker, installation, pip, docker-container

During the last three months I've developed several ***Python*** (***Python3.6.9***) system oriented applications on ***Centos7.8***.
These applications are using the ***sys***, ***subprocess*** and ***timeit*** packages, which where installed on May 2020 by ***pip install***.

Now I was requested to create a ***Docker container*** with these applications and tried to ***pip install*** the listed packages within the container (starting with ***sys***):

```
sudo docker run -i -t centos/python-36-centos7 /bin/bash
(app-root) python -V
Python 3.6.9

(app-root) pip install sys
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sys (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sys
```

The listed packages weren't found and failed to install with the same ERROR messages.

What might be a problem and how should I solve it ?

Thanks

Zeev

Comment: `sys`, `subprocess`, and `timeit` should all be part of the standard library and thus cannot be pip-installed

Answer (score 3):

Sys, subprocess, timeit, etc are standard libraries(you don't need to install them, they come with the pyhton installation candidate) of python, so using pip to install them is pretty useless. Just reinstall python, maybe your python's standard libs are overwritten by other third party package.

Comment: my_app.py: import sys
...

docker response:
... sys is missing ...

Answer (score 1):

Before asking the forum, I've used Docker container based on ***Python3.6***.
It complained regarding the missing ***sys***, ***subprocess***, ***timeit*** packages. These standard packages were supposed to be contained by default - as wrote ROG_SHAKHYAR.

After updating to ***Python3.6.9*** , I've checked again, and suddenly realized that everything functions well.
So, the issue was solved ... :)

My great thanks and appreciation to ROG_SHAKHYAR.

Comment: can you show the output of it complaining?  I have my doubts